# How to get results that begin with a certain letter?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a method similar to the following, which I need to return all Groups that begin with the letter I'm passing in:

```
public IList<CompanyGroupInfo> GetGroupByQuery(string letter)
{
    IList<CompanyGroupInfo> result = null;

    result = _session
        .CreateCriteria<CompanyGroupInfo>()
        .Add(SqlExpression.Like<CompanyGroupInfo>(g => g.Name, letter))
        .List<CompanyGroupInfo>();

    return (result.Count > 0) ? result[0] : null;
}
```

I'm brand new to NHibernate, so I don't really know what to do here. In my mind, it'd be ideal if there was a `SqlExpression.StartsWith` method, but there isn't. Is it as simple as modifying the expression so that

```
        .Add(SqlExpression.Like<CompanyGroupInfo>(g => g.Name, letter))
```

becomes something like

```
        .Add(SqlExpression.Like<CompanyGroupInfo>(g => g.Name.StartsWith(letter)))
```

Can somebody please point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a distinct list of first letters with NHibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184957/how-to-get-a-distinct-list-of-first-letters-with-nhibernate)

Comment: @Ekberg not even close to being a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at the docs, I *suspect* you want:

```
SqlExpression.Like<CompanyGroupInfo>(g => g.Name, letter, MatchMode.Start)
```

but I haven't used NHibernate for ages...

Answer (score 1):

I think this

```
SqlExpression.Like<CompanyGroupInfo>(g => g.Name, letter + "%")
```